# openssl is not creating certificates with expected expiration date

Tags: date, openssl, certificates

I have a self signed root CA certificate and key

I am trying to create a server certificate which will be signed by this CA

Here are the steps I took:

1) Generate a server key

`openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048`

2) Generate a signing request specifying 365 days

`openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -days 365 -sha256`

3) Sign the request using the self signed CA

`openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA CA.crt -CAkey CA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -sha256`

When I check my newly created cert as follows:

`openssl x509 -noout -text -in server.crt`

I can see this in the output:

`Validity
            Not Before: May  8 14:19:44 2017 GMT
            Not After : Jun  7 14:19:44 2017 GMT`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? Why didn't it create a cert with the correct expiration date even though I specified 365 days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The certificate validity should be specified in the last step as in:

`openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA CA.crt -CAkey CA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -sha256 -days 365`

Otherwise, while you are requesting 365 days while creating the CSR, when you sign it the signing default configuration overrides the days of the CSR request.